# How to train Keras model on TPU on Google Colab ?, do I need to change my model configuration?(tinyYolo-v3)

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, yolo, tpu

I am not very familiar to model training on Google Colaboratory, I am currently trying to train  a Keras (tinyYolov3) model using TPU, from my understanding I need get one of of the available TPU devices using

```
    resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu_address)
    tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
    strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

and build and compile my model with
with strategy.scope():

```
    model = create_tiny_model(input_shape, anchors, num_classes,
    freeze_body, )
    
    model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True, skip_mismatch=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), loss={
    # use custom yolo_loss Lambda layer.
    'yolo_loss': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred})
    model.summary()
    print('Load weights {}.'.format(weights_path))
```

The following code seems to when the problem occurs

```
    def data_generator(annotation_lines, batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes):
    '''data generator for fit_generator'''
    n = len(annotation_lines)
    i = 0
    while True:
        image_data = []
        box_data = []
        for b in range(batch_size):
            if i==0:
                np.random.shuffle(annotation_lines)
            image, box = get_random_data(annotation_lines[i], input_shape, random=True)
            image_data.append(image)
            box_data.append(box)
            i = (i+1) % n
        image_data = np.array(image_data)
        box_data = np.array(box_data)
        y_true = preprocess_true_boxes(box_data, input_shape, anchors, num_classes)
        yield [image_data, *y_true], np.zeros(batch_size)

    def data_generator_wrapper(annotation_lines, batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes):
     n = len(annotation_lines)
     if n==0 or batch_size<=0: return None
     return data_generator(annotation_lines, batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes)
```

ERROR message

```
         60 
         61 def _pop_per_thread_mode():
    ---> 62   ops.get_default_graph()._distribution_strategy_stack.pop(-1)  # pylint:     disable=protected-access
         63 
         64 

    IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I also tried
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

```
    yolo_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
        yolo_model,
        strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
                    tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
```

and get the following message:
ValueError:
Layer <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x7f5cbab05dd8>         has a variable shape in a non-batch dimension.  TPU models must
have constant shapes for all operations.

```
    You may have to specify `input_length` for RNN/TimeDistributed layers.

    Layer: <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x7f5cbab05dd8>
    Input shape: (None, None, None, 3)
    Output shape: (None, None, None, 3)
```

Comment: Is that all the error output?

Comment: the error output included the traceback before the error, and I did not include it, but I added the method where the call happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my code. To me, what solved this error was to comment  "tf.keras.backend.clear_session()" within the "with strategy.scope():".

By doing so I can train my model on a TPU (in Google colab) although much slower than with that line uncommented.
I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).